# Why do I get a NullPointerException when using text input as opposed to user input?

Tags: java

So I have to write a program that is a flight reservation system. If I run the program normally and enter in values when prompted, nothing goes wrong, but when I use a .txt file input, I get a `NullPointerException`. The part of the code im getting the `NullPointerException` is

```
 public void instantiateAirplane() throws IOException{
        boolean creatingAirplane = true;
        String className= "";
        String seatFormat;
        int rowNums;
        while (creatingAirplane){
            input  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter service class name or [ENTER] to finish: ");

            className = input.readLine();
            if (className.equals("")) {
                creatingAirplane = false;
            }
            else{   
                System.out.println("Enter seating pattern: ");
                seatFormat = input.readLine();
                System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
                rowNums = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
                plane.creatSeatingChart(className, rowNums, seatFormat);
            }
        }
    }
```

When doing normal input, it runs like this:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Math&CIS\CS151\HW1>java UserInterface planes
Enter service class name or [ENTER] to finish:
First Class
Enter seating pattern:
WAAW
Enter number of rows:
2
Enter service class name or [ENTER] to finish:
Business Class
Enter seating pattern:
WAAW
Enter number of rows:
2
Enter service class name or [ENTER] to finish:

Add [P]assenger, Add [G]roup, [C]ancel Reservations, Print [S]eating chart, Prin
t [M]anifest, [Q]uit
```

But when when using a .txt input, the following happens

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Math&CIS\CS151\HW1>java UserInterface planes < input.txt
Enter service class name or [ENTER] to finish:
Enter seating pattern:
Enter number of rows:
Enter service class name or [ENTER] to finish:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at UserInterface.instantiateAirplane(UserInterface.java:21)
        at UserInterface.main(UserInterface.java:123)

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Math&CIS\CS151\HW1>
```

the exception happens at the line "`if (className.equals("")) {`"

the input text is the follwing:

```
First
WAAW
2
Economy
WCAACW
3

...
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work when using an input text.

Comment: Can you confirm that has your code `if (className.equals("")) {` this statement at `line 21` in `UserInterface.java` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That readLine() method returns a null once the iterator reaches what is known as EOF or the end of file. Check to see if `ClassName == null || className.Equal("")...`

Also you may want to declare `input  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` out side of your loop just so you are not re-initializing the reader at each loop iteration.

-!

Comment: Thanks for that second tip. that was what the problem was. i just instantiated input where it is declared and deleted all the other instantiations and the problem was fixed. thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, being stuck stinks!

Answer (score 1):

When you read successive lines from a file with readLine, you get a null back if you read past end of file.

Answer (score 1):

`readLine` returns "null if the end of the stream has been reached".

The two are behaving differently because (I presume) you entered "Q" from the keyboard but you didn't put a "Q" in your input file.

Note: I'm not saying you should place a "Q" in the file; you should be checking for `null` in the code.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But the problem im running into isnt from reaching the end of the stream. it returns null after reading the line "2". it doesnt get to "economy", and exception is thrown before it

Answer (score 0):

That `readLine()` method returns null at the end of the file.  Thats different from "" which you get when you hit enter.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

You could change the test to `if (className == null || className.equals("")) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop creating the airplane upon encountering the empty String (""), then your file will need an empty line in it: empty line meaning two line separators with nothing between them. If you instead mean to read to the end of the file, you should stop when you see a `null`, as other posters have said.